# Counting number of the orders

Tags: combinatorics

Good evening! I'm stuck on how to approach "wording" problem below:

There are 5 candies and 5 chocolate bars. When the girl eats candy, she shrinks to half her current size, and when she eats chocolate, she becomes two times larger. In how many orders can she eat all treats on the table, if she can’t reach them when her size is smaller than original?

Is there any specific way to approach such problems?

Thank you!

Comment: The correct search term to look for here is "*[Catalan Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number)*" and "*[Dyck Words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyck_language)*"

Comment: I see, so this is "mountain range" problem. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition is essentially that she must eat at least $n$ chocolate bars before each $n$th candy. In this case, the numbers are small enough to brute-force, and that's likely the expected solution. I'll try to at least be marginally clever about my brute forcing, and start with an arbitrary number $c$ of candies and $b$ of chocolate bars, and denote by $N(b,c)$ the number of possible orderings beginning with $c$ candies and $b$ bars:

Now, we have a few cases: if $b = c$, then she is at her starting size, and the first action must be to eat a chocolate bar. That is: $N(b,b) = N(b-1,c)$. If, on the other hand, $0 < b < c$, then then she can either eat a chocolate bar or a candy. That is: $N(b,c) = N(b-1,c) + N(b,c-1)$. Finally, if $b = 0$, then she must eat a candy. That is, $N(0,c) = N(0,c-1)$. In particular, we have $N(0,1) = 1$, so $N(0,c) = 1$ for all $c$.

Now, we can proceed inductively:

\begin{align*}N(5,5) &= N(4,5) \\&= N(4,4) + N(3,5) 
\\&= N(3,4) + N(2,5) + N(2,5) \\&= N(3,4) + 2N(2,5)
\\&= N(2,4) + N(3,3) + 2(N(1,5) + N(2,4))
\\&= 3N(2,4) + 2N(1,5) + N(3,3)
\\&= 3(N(1,4) + N(2,3)) + 2(N(1,4) + N(0,5)) + N(2,3)
\\&= 5N(1,4) + 4N(2,3) + 2
\\&= 5(N(0,4) + N(1,3)) + 4(N(1,3) + N(2,2)) + 2
\\&= 9N(1,3) + 4N(2,2) + 7
\\&= 9(N(0,3) + N(1,2)) + 4N(1,2) + 7
\\&= 13N(1,2) + 16
\\&= 13(N(0,2) + N(1,1)) + 16
\\&= 13N(1,1) + 29
\\&= 13N(0,1) + 29
\\&= 42.
\end{align*}

Comment: I cannot imagine that brute force could possibly be the intended solution here...  You got the right number, but this is so obviously a catalan number problem and catalan numbers are so immensely important to so many different counting problems that surely you can expect that they were taught.  The answer is very simply $C[5]$, and answering as such would be more than adequate.

Comment: This looks an awful lot like a grade-school maths question to me, so I'm fairly sure the intended solution is not via Catalan numbers.

Answer (score 1):

As alluded to in my comments, this is very simply the fifth Catalan number, $C[5] = \frac{1}{6}\times\binom{10}{5} = 42$

The only challenge should have been in remembering what the Catalan numbers were and that this problem matches one of the many common problem types that Catalan numbers are used to solve.  Several proofs and uses of the Catalan numbers can be found [on their wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number)